# Inserting 2 Images in a Single Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and request your assistance for the below query.

**QUERY:**

I want to insert two images, one below the other, in a Cell say B2 with already pre-configured enough Cell height and width.
I am using the below code

```
 .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Left
 .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Top
```

where in my 1st image is placed at the Top,Left of the Cell.Now how do i place the 2nd image in the same cell below the 1st image.

Is there any command like `.Bottom`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no command like `.Bottom`, but an alternate approach for you could be simply adding the height of the first image to the top of the cell to decide where it ends. I.e.:

```
image2.Top = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Top + image1.Height
```